# How to prove $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{3}+y^{3}}$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I have tried using polar coordinates and several polynomial functions, but they all converge to the value of $0$; checking at Wolfram Alpha, however, it confirms that the limit does not exist. How should I approach these kinds of questions and not get stuck? 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{3}+y^{3}}
$$

Comment: The questions are identical, yet each discussion on the solution was distinct. I'm new to the website, should this post be deleted?

Comment: IMO yes, need to delete. but the vote of the people is decisive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

- $x=0 \implies f(0,y)=0$
- $ x=t \quad y=-t+t^2 \quad t\to 0$ $$\implies\frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}=
     \frac{t^2(t^2-2t^3+t^4)}{t^3-t^3+3t^4-3t^5+t^6}=\frac{1-2t+t^2}{3-3t+t^2}\to \frac13$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz thanks for the edit but I really mean that f(0,y) is identically zero for $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$ and therefore also $f(0,y)\to 0$ as a consequence.

Comment: Thank you. Is this something done simply by trial and error or is there some kind of reasoning behind the value?

Comment: @Nucleus The key point is use a path such that the denominator is "near" to the points such that $x^3+y^3=0$. Therefore for $x=t$ we need to take $y=-t$ and to have path in the domain we add to $y$ a negligible term with respect to $t$ that is $t^2$.

Comment: @Nucleus Sometime we need some trial and error but following these rules is  usually a very good start point in order to find these "critical paths".

Comment: @Nucleus I also suggest to use paths given in parametric form since in that way it is often easier and much clear to proceed with the derivation of the value in the limit.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a specific way to suspect that the limit didn't exist in this case, even with polar coordinate substitution converging to a value?

Comment: @Nucleus Obviously near the zeroes of the denominator (true zeroes, tending to a point in question).

Comment: @Nucleus The first trial by polar coordinates is useful to see if we can reduce to an expression in the form $$r^a \cdot f(\theta)$$ indeed when $a>0$ and $f(\theta)$ is bounded we can conclude. For example in that case we obtain $a=1$ but the expression for $f(\theta)$ is not bounded then we can't conlude by polar coordinates and we need to check for specific paths.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, I understand, but at that point, the important thing is that the limit is $0$. The contradiction comes from having two series converging to the origin where the values converge to different numbers. This is the relevant thing, even though your claim is stronger. Anyway, it is your party, and your original answer is correct, so no problem.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Yes indeed my point is that, since along the $y$ axis for any $y\neq 0$, the function reduces to the zero function of course we have (on those paths) $0\to 0$. I hope that it is clarified now. Thanks again for your kind and interesting observations! Any open discussionis here is useful to better clarify thinkgs. Have a nice day! Bye

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Take, e.g., $y^3=-x^3+x^6$.
The easiest way is to prove now that
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left(\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{3}+y^{3}}\right)^3
$$
does not exist.

Comment: I've tried substituting the values with (x,-x^3+x^2), but the limit towards 0 remained true as the expression turned to (-x^3+x^2)^(2/3).

Comment: @Nucleus Oh, sorry: corrected.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get why the whole equation is being exponentiated to the power of 3

Comment: @Nucleus Then it is easy to see that in denominator you have $x^{18}$ and in numerator an expression which behaves near zero as $x^{12}$.